# How do i print a row with 3 equally sized cells under a row with 4 cells? HTML

Tags: html

The following does not achieve the result

```
<tr><td colspan="4">Title</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33.33%">1</td><td width="33.33%">2</td><td width="33.33%">3</td></tr>
<tr><td width="33.33%">&nbsp;</td><td width="33.33%"></td><td width="33.33%"></td></tr>
```

The there is an extra space after the third cell to take into account the 4th column. How can I remove this so that the entire row is equally divided into three cells that fill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equal widths you should create 2 table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="4">Title</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q57gW/2/

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to not use table. If you REALLY need that table, one (very messy) soultion could be to have 12 columns in each row, and have colspan="3" in your first row, and colspan="4" in your other rows.

[jsfiddle link for this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hq5pQ/)

```
<table><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 240px;" colspan="12">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 60px;" colspan="3">1</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 60px;" colspan="3">1</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 60px;" colspan="3">1</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 60px;" colspan="3">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 80px;" colspan="4">1</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 80px;" colspan="4">2</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333; width: 80px;" colspan="4">3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

But I would HEAVILY advice you to use divs or spans or something else than table cells. Here's a much nicer solution using paragraphs:

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hq5pQ/2/)

html:

```
<div style="width: 240px;">
    <p class="onecell">Title</p>
    <p class="fourcell">1</p><p class="fourcell">1</p><p class="fourcell">1</p><p class="fourcell">1</p>
    <p class="threecell">1</p><p class="threecell">2</p><p class="threecell">3</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
p {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
p.onecell {
    width: 100%;
}
p.fourcell {
    width: 25%;
}
p.threecell {
    width: 33%;
}
```